# Why is Cauchy horizon named after Cauchy?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, terminology

I think the title says it all; I have done a lot of Googling, but I could not find the answer.

Since (I assume) the concept was discovered after Cauchy's death, I speculate that there is a connection between [Cauchy horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_horizon) and some other (most likely mathematical) notion named after Cauchy (perhaps Cauchy sequences).

Comment: Presumably because of the notion of a [Cauchy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface).

Comment: Also [Cauchy boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_boundary_condition)

Comment: @Qmechanic That is certainly the case. It just shift the question of why Cauchy surfaces are named after Cauchy though.

Comment: It is the limit/boundary up to which the Cauchy problem has an unique solution. That is why it is a horizon, you can't "see" beyond it, and that's why it is Cauchy, it is about the Cauchy problem.